# Access the string value from a Dictionary

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have the following Code :

```
a= {'b': '{"c":46, "d": 1}', 'e': 10}
```

Here I need to get the value of `"c"` in a dictionary inside another dictionary, but the value of `'b'` is a dictionary which is in string format.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to decode the string value from JSON format into a Python object like the following (using [python's json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)):

```
import json

b_value = json.loads(a['b']) # decode the value from JSON string
c_value = b_value['c'] # use/access the value
```